# $[F(a):F] \leq [\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ - proof?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $F \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

I'm trying to prove that $[F(a):F] \leq [\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ (where $F(a) := \mathbb{Q}(F\cup\left\{ {a}\right\}))$ and deduce from this that the set of complex numbers which are algebraic over the rationals is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

For the first part, I guess $a$ has to be algebraic to ensure the two degrees are finite. Now as $F$ is a field, certainly $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq F$. Then I've tried thinking in terms of minimal polynomials but I get completely confused and dont really see how to provide a rigorous proof... Also, I don't really see how I could use such a result to show the last part.

I've been going round and round about this and got no result, could you hint me please? It would really help me as I'm only starting to read about field extensions and am not familiar with them!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K\subset \Omega$ is a field extension, and $a \in \Omega$, then

$$[K(a) : K] = 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\mbox{degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$} & \mbox{if $a$ is algebraic} \\
\infty & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

Given this preliminary lemma, the exercise now is trivial.

If $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$), then it is algebraic over $F$. Let $m \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ , and $n \in F[X]$ be its minimal polynomial over $F$.

But $\mathbb{Q}[X] \subset F[X]$, so $n$ divides $m$, and in particular its degree is smaller.

As for the second part: let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 0\}$ algebraic. Then $a+b, a-b, ab, a/b \in \mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ We want to show that they are algebraic. It is sufficient to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b) : \mathbb{Q}] < \infty$. And now
$$[\mathbb{Q}(a,b) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(a,b) : \mathbb{Q}(a)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}] \leq [\mathbb{Q}(b) : \mathbb{Q}] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}]$$
hence it is finite.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're right, it's trivial in the end... What could you say about the second part?

Comment: The definition of minimal polynomial is the following: it is the polynomial dividing every other polynomial which has $a$ as a root. Since $m(a)=0$ and $m \in F[X]$, then $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second part of my question, your answer was perfectly clear! "deduce from this that the set of complex numbers which are algebraic over the rationals is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$"

Comment: Why is it sufficient to show the finiteness of this degree?

Comment: Because every finite extension is algebraic.

Comment: Yes, right, thank you very much for this complete rigorous proof! It helped a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;P_F(x)\,,\,\,P_{\Bbb Q}(x)\;$ be the minimal polynomial of $\;a\;$ over $\;F\,,\,\,\Bbb Q\;$ , resp., so that

$$[F(a):F]=\deg P_F(x)\;\;,\;\;\;[\Bbb Q(a):\Bbb Q]=\deg P_{\Bbb Q}(x)$$

But we certainly have that *also*

$$\;P_{\Bbb Q}(x)\in F[x]\;\implies\;\; P_F(x)\mid P_{\Bbb Q}(x)\implies \deg P_F(X)\le\deg P_{\Bbb Q}(x)$$

adn we're done.

Comment: Oh wow, I did this, the wrong way around every single time and therefore always got confused... Thank you for your help ! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: Do you have any idea for the second part? The deduction?

Comment: I can't see a direct deduction for the second part from the first one . I'd use that $$[\Bbb Q(a):\Bbb Q]=\alpha<\infty \;,\;\;[\Bbb Q(b):\Bbb Q]=\beta<\infty\implies [\Bbb Q(a,b):\Bbb Q]\le\alpha\beta$$

Comment: Your comment does not take a normal form for me, it  stays in code form...